# copying the first two values from textbox

Tags: javascript

how to copy the first two letters only using this code? i really dont know how

```
function sync() {
    var c = document.getElementById('c');
    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    a.value = c.value;
}
```

Comment: Copy the letters? What do you mean?

Comment: this code can copy value from from c bu what i am trying is that only the first two letters only not the whole letters from c

Comment: only first two letters,, umm.. c.value.slice(0,2)

Comment: im just newbie in programming sir :)

Comment: Use the [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string slice method:

```
MyString.slice(0,2); //returns a new string with only the first two chars.
```

So you could write:

```
function sync() {
    var c = document.getElementById('c');
    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    a.value = c.value.slice(0,2);// a now contains the first two chars from c
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what i've understood i expect that , `c` is the `id` of your `textbox` and  `a` is the `id` of your field into which you are trying to copy.

If it's so, then use this code :

```
function sync() {
    var c = document.getElementById('c').value;
    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    a.value = c.substring(0,2);
}
```

Use the `substring()` function

Comment: Is it a typo? `c.substring(0,2);`

Comment: I didn't intended to be rude. Sorry. I just want to make clear about the type of `c`. It's a DOM not a string, then the statement should be `c.value.substring(0,2);`

Comment: if you see this correctly `var c = document.getElementById('c').value;` you can find that i'm assigning `var c` the `value` of the `document.getElementById('c')` , but not the DOM itself

Comment: Oops! You're right. But your code then could make others confused, at least me :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would get the fist two letter of an input field
http://jsfiddle.net/qKh8P

```
$('.abbr').on('keydown', function(){
    var abbr = $(this).val().slice(0,2);
    if(abbr.length > 1){ alert('abbrev: ' + abbr); }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but it contains a lot of code (event handlers, alerts, etc) that isn't necessarily germane to the question (plus it's reliant on an external library that, it seems, the OP is not using).

Comment: You can do what i did entirely in JavaScript as well people nowadays always ask for a jQuery version especially noobies

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [JavasScript substring() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp). substring() and substr() will both get the job done. Here's [a good comparison of the two methods](http://rapd.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/javascript-substr-vs-substring/).

A small change to your function should do the trick:

```
<script>
function sync() {
    var c = document.getElementById('c');
    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    a.value = c.value.substring(0,2);
}
</script>
```

So if your markup for a and c started like this:

```
<input id="a" value="">
<input id="c" value="answer">
```

This is what would happen after calling the sync() function:

```
<input id="a" value="an">
<input id="c" value="answer">
```